# Updating comment count for a post in recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, comments, notifydatasetchanged

Activity A has a recycler view , which has each row as a post, now each post has a comment button  which launches a comment activity where user can see comments and also add comments. Now question is, 
After adding comment(s), how do I update the comment count in particular row of recycler view in activity A when comment Activity finishes, **without notifydatasetchanged()** , since I don't wanna reload the recycler view again.

Comment: Would `RecyclerView.Adapter.notifyItemChanged(int position);` or `RecyclerView.Adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(int positionStart, int positionEnd);` work for you?

Comment: Both works for me. It's just I don't wanna reload the whole thing, these commands reload the recycler view. Rather I want only comment count to increase.

Comment: Use an Interface then.

Comment: @Nidhi can you provide code snippet ?

Comment: @AsifAli How did you solve this problem? If you can put the answer here it will be very helpful